# Combination of 2 × 1 × 1 cubes inside a 3 × 3 × n cube

Tags: packing-and-covering

You have a block with a width of 3, depth of 3 and a height n
Given n, in how many ways can you fill this block with smaller blocks of 2 x 1 x 1?

if n is uneven, one 1x1x1 block will be unused. This is allowed.

Comment: Are you sure it is research level? What methods have you tried before? Are there any numerical results for small $n$?

Comment: This is an instance of the dimer problem, which has a large literature.

Comment: I was indeed not sure if this was research level, but no one on math.stackexchange could solve it, so i went a little higher. Yes there is a reason for the size. This is actually a part of a larger question. A 2x1x1 block represents 2 twin brothers, and the big block represents a building. In how many ways can twins be placed in adjacent rooms in this building. Thanks, i will look up the dimer problem.

Comment: This is a Project Euler question, http://projecteuler.net/problem=324.

Comment: Compute a few terms. Look up a sequence of 4 small values or one large value in the OEIS. (I just used the term for $n=4$ from Zack Wolske's Project Euler link.) http://oeis.org/A028452 This covers the case of even $n$.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Project Euler question.

Comment: Asked at [Mathematics StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/524582/18398).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity, I'll assume $n$ is even.  Each horizontal slice of the $3 \times 3 \times n$ block can have a finite number of "states".  Each state consists of a packing of the $3 \times 3$ square with $2 \times 1$ blocks (in either orientation) and $1 \times 1$ blocks, where the $1 \times 1$ blocks are labelled either ``$+$ or $-$''.  The lowest slice is not allowed to have any $-$, the highest slice is not allowed any $+$, and each $+$ must be paired with a $-$ in the next higher level.  If there are $N$ states $1 \ldots N$, let $A$ be the
adjacency matrix: $A_{ij} = 1$ if state $i$ in one level is compatible with
state $j$ in the next level, $0$ otherwise.  Let $L$ and $H$ be the column vectors
of $0$'s and $1$'s indicating states that are possible in the lowest and highest
levels respectively.  Then the number of ways is $L^T A^{n-2} H$. The eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$ can be used to compute this.